# Zabbix - Include hostname in Grafana notification to MS Teams

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams, zabbix, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana with Zabbix plugin. I am able to set the alerts but I can't find the way to include the hostname of the affected VM.

I have attached the current configuration and how the alert in MS Teams looks like. I tried using $host ${host} in the message template which didn't work

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: zabbix already has a notification feature. why not using it?

Comment: @IronBishop I am combining multiple queries in the alerts which Zabbix doesn't have an easy way of doing (or at least I am not aware of). For example, Items that are available for the trigger directly on the host are not offered when trying to create the Trigger on the "Windows by Zabbix Agent" template.

Comment: you can select the item in the "add" interface of the trigger

Comment: I added more screenshots of the difference I am seeing on the "Windows by Zabbix agent" vs on the host itself @IronBishop. I understand that these are the low level items that are missing in Windows by Zabbix agent but I am not sure how to add them.

Comment: use {HOST.NAME} or {HOST.IP} in the message template